# how do make a working python program run without errors when executed from .bashrc

Tags: python, linux, bash

I know very little about bash script programming and python programming, but I'm tasked with taking a python program that works when launched in a term window and moving it to a .bashrc file so it automatically runs at boot up (debian on raspberry pi).
In a term window I run the command successfully like this:

```
prompt> cd /var/www

prompt> python mod_pywebsocket/standalone.py -p 5555
```

I have put this line in the .bashrc file and it runs, but not property:

```
/usr/bin/python /var/www/pywebsocket/standalone.py -p 5555
```

I get several warnings that I don't understand, but it looks like the various layers of python programs/functions are not finding functions/variables/objects that they need.

Is there a simple way to invoke the python program as if I were actually in a term window in the /var/www directory and have all of the scoping, etc. work?

Or is there a completely different way to autostart the program from the /var/www directory?

Thanks very much,
Steve

Comment: What are the errors? You didn't put in the bashrc what you typed at the prompt (cd first and then execute), so your results may not match.

Comment: What makes you think you have to change it at all? You can just copy/paste your two commands into your .bashrc.

Comment: Why are you executing a completely different script in the bashrc? Type into the end of the bashrc precisely  what you typed at the command line and tell us if that doesn't work.

Comment: To clarify, on the command line you run /var/www/mod_pywebsocket/standalone.py and in your .bashrc you run /var/www/pywebsocket/standalone.py. Notice the **mod_**.

Comment: If you want this script to run at boot, you do **not** want to put it in your .bashrc; that runs when you start an interactive non-login shell, which is completely different from what you want. To make something run at boot under Debian (or any other distro that uses System V-style init), you should create an init script and place it under /etc/init.d/ (see [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian) and [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon))

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess I'd say the script is using some relative paths and requires being executed within /var/www. You could solve this in your bashrc via

```
pushd /var/www
    python mod_pywebsocket/standalone.py -p 5555
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

The bashrc file executes commands just as if they were typed at the command line, except they execute on login or shell invocation. If it works at the CLI, type the exact same thing into the bashrc.

Bear in mind that your command will execute every time that user logs in or runs a shell for some reason. You may not intend for this server to run in all of those instances.

Answer (score 0):

Why not place the exact working commands into your .bashrc?

```
cd /var/www && python mod_pywebsocket/standalone.py -p 5555
```

For some programs, it matters what directory you launch it from, and so here we switch to `/var/www` first.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the script executable and link the script to somewhere in your `$PATH` ie: `/usr/local/sbin`.

```
ln -s /var/www/pywebsocket/standalone.py /usr/local/sbin/standalone
```

Then, call the script from `.bashrc` as:

```
standalone -p 5555
```